Data exchange between a Modelica model and a fast language (e.g. neural networks)
I want to ask which software to use between OpenModelica models (used for machine hardware parameter determination) and an external program that exchanges data with the Modelica model (this should be a language capable of building and training advanced neural networks).
The external program determines, for example, control parameters for the Modelica model.
Right now, I'm leaning towards Julia.
